# GAE Datastore: “total” property vs. adding up line items?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, data-modeling

This is another Google App Engine Datastore question.

Let’s say my app tracks a bunch of rats and how much cheese they’ve eaten.  Each `Rat` entity has a series of `Meal` entities -- each tracks when the rat ate and how many slices of cheese (`slices` property).  Each `Rat` also has a `total_slices` property that is updated whenever a new meal is logged.

Should I abandon the `total_slices` property in favor of simply adding up the `slices` of each `Meal` whenever I need to know the total?  The Datastore documentation says that queries are cheap, while updating an entity at a high frequency is problematic (Google defines “high frequency” as updating an entity more than once a second at a sustained rate).  So if I have some really voracious rats that feast more than once a second, I’m risking a timeout when I update the `Rat`’s `total_slices`.

Any suggestions how to best design this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two separate issues wrapped up in your question:

**1. Should you de-normalize `total_slices` to the `Rat` entity?**

To answer this you must analyze the data access patterns of your application.  For example:

- Is getting `total_slices` for a `Rat` a
  common task?
- Will you ever need to
  list or sort `Rats` by `total_slices`?
- Will adding up each `Meal` still be
  efficient after several years of data
  have accumulated?

**2. What do you do in GAE if you have an entity that needs to be updated more than 1/sec?**

Use a [Sharded Counter](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters.html).